# parsing @ in MVC javascript section?

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying using Email `RegEx` in javascript section in MVC4. But `RegEx` has @ char. It is not allowing to parse it

```
error:

Parser Error Message: "[" is not valid at the start of a code block.  
        Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.
```

### code

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#btnSave, #btnCoAuthor').click(function() {
                if (form.valid()) {
                    var hasError = false;
                    var emailReg = '[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}';
                      //Error showing @
```

Comment: Dupe.  Escape it using a double @.  `]+@@[`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to escape the `@` *for Razor*, not for the JS string, itself. So, just use `@@`. Once Razor renders the HTML, it will end up as just an `@`.

Comment: I get an error saying 'Parser Error Message: "@" is not valid at the start of a code block. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.'. It's a pretty clean installation, any ideas for further debugging? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Escaping with `@@` works for me

```
var emailReg = '[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}';
```

and output HTML is

```
var emailReg = '[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an escape sequence in JS, like:

```
var at = "\u0040";
```